# XSLT Attributes are not included in the output after transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to implement one simple xslt, to add one node under the root node.

Here is my input.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root a="a">
    <itemizedlist role="type6" id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL2392155.512">
        <listitem id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL6440405.513"><para id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL35914597.514">Glasform mit Deckel auf dem Rost, Höhe 1</para></listitem>
        <listitem id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL35935428.515"><para id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL6441139.516">Mikrowelle 600 Watt</para></listitem>
        <listitem id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL37145770.517"><para id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL37145771.518">Schalotten, Lauch: 4 Minuten</para></listitem>
        <listitem id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL37151364.519"><para id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL37151365.520">Fleisch, Gemüse, Nudeln: 10-12 Minuten</para></listitem>
        <listitem id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL42243432.521"><para id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL42243433.522">danach</para></listitem>
        <listitem id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL42243434.523"><para id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL42243435.524">Mikrowelle 1000 Watt</para></listitem>
        <listitem id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL42243436.525"><para id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL42243437.526">Bouillon: 5-6 Minuten</para></listitem>
    </itemizedlist>
</root>
```

I am implementing xsl to put one "dummy" div before all listitem nodes.

Here is xsl file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"  encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">

    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="itemizedlist[@role='type6']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <div class="recipe_placeholder"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is like this :

```
<root a="a">
    <itemizedlist><div class="recipe_placeholder"/>
        <listitem id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL6440405.513"><para id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL35914597.514">Glasform mit Deckel auf dem Rost, Höhe 1</para>
</listitem>
        <listitem id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL35935428.515"><para id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL6441139.516">Mikrowelle 600 Watt</para>
</listitem>
        <listitem id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL37145770.517"><para id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL37145771.518">Schalotten, Lauch: 4 Minuten</para>
</listitem>
        <listitem id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL37151364.519"><para id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL37151365.520">Fleisch, Gemüse, Nudeln: 10-12 Minuten</para>
</listitem>
        <listitem id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL42243432.521"><para id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL42243433.522">danach</para>
</listitem>
        <listitem id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL42243434.523"><para id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL42243435.524">Mikrowelle 1000 Watt</para>
</listitem>
        <listitem id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL42243436.525"><para id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL42243437.526">Bouillon: 5-6 Minuten</para>
</listitem>
    </itemizedlist>
</root>
```

Question is that on the output i can't see the attributes of itemizedlist, that i am adding one "div" element , on xsl transformation. Output shows it as

```
<itemizedlist>
```

Desired one is that :

```
<itemizedlist role="type6" id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a43205230.SL2392155.512">
```

What i am doing wrong ? Is there another parameter to protect attribute values or not ?

Many thanks your answers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must copy the attributes of `itemizedlist` **before** you start the next element `<div>`:

```
<xsl:template match="itemizedlist[@role='type6']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <div class="recipe_placeholder"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Uuups i haven't seen that, small detail :) Many thanks for your answer!